# IIS not picking up on changes made to my code

Tags: iis, iis-7

Why doesn't my iis Server pick up changes to local code? I've changed both css/js files and changed some images but iis just doesn't update anything on the website. I've tried restarting the website and refreshing it on the iis manager but nothing changes.

However when i edit the web.config file it detects it automatically. Why is this? and how can I let the iis server website know that I have changed local files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any kind of CDN that has the page cached?
If so, you can purge the cache of that URL.

Also test if the changes update when you use Private Browsing/Incognito Mode on your browser.  If this shows the updated page, then it is your browser cache that needs to be cleared.

But to really solve the problem, you'll want to version the JS page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011605/clear-the-cache-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is your browser cache.

For Chrome and Firefox you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force refresh the page.

Failing that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and clear the cache.